# Prove that $G$ is connected if $δ(G) ≥ (v−1)/2$

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a graph has v vertices and $δ(G) ≥ (v−1)/2$. Prove that $G$ is connected.

Comment: Suppose that $G$ *wasn't* connected.  Then... there must be at least two connected components (*why?*), and one of them must have less than or equal to half of the vertices (*why?*).  Then, consider some vertex in that connected component and what its degree implies about the number of vertices in that component.

Comment: what is $\delta$ of a graph?

Comment: δ(G) indicates the smallest number of all degrees of vertices of G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any two $A$ and $B$. If they are connected we are done. Suppose they are not.
Let $N(X)$ be a set of neighbors of vertex $X$. Then $N(X)\geq (n-1)/2 $ for each vertex $X$ by assumption. Remember we have $$|N(A)\cup N(B)| = |N(A)|+|N(B)|-  |N(A)\cap N(B)|$$

If $|N(A)\cap N(B)| =0$ we have $$n-2\geq |N(A)\cup N(B)|\geq 2\cdot {n-1\over 2} =n-1$$

wich is a contradiction. So $N(A)\cap N(B) \ne \emptyset$ and thus there is some vertex which is adjacent to $A$ and $B$.

Comment: sorry! but why the union is less than or equal (n-2).

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are not connected $A$ is not in $N(B)$ (and not in $N(A)$ if we assume there is no loop in the graph), so $A\notin N(A)\cup N(B)$. The same is true for $B$.

Comment: thanks a lot :)